# Matchmaking software

Tags: rules-engine

what are software's available that provide a matchmaking service. I.e if I have a user with specific attributes(income, age, nationality,....) he gets matched with a relevant University(high rank,tuition based on user income,....). I am writing my code in angular and node js if the software or even library are compatible with node and angular that would be great.

Thank you

Comment: I don't think that's called a "rule engine", but I get the idea. You tagged the question as "machine-learning"... as you know, machine learning needs a lot of data to learn from. Do you have thousands of ideal matches that the software should use for machine learning?

Comment: I guess you want a library to insert into your software/webapp? If so, what programming languages does your software use? (serverside if a webapp)

Comment: Please edit to clarify your question then ask us to reopen, thanks!